# WCF custom serialization

Tags: json, wcf, serialization

I'm using .Net Framework WCF. This application receive json requests and response json string.
I would like to use my own serialization library for the serialization and deserialization actions.

In asp.net I used to do it in Global.asax file:

```
IJsonSerializer serializer = new Serializer();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new CustomFormatter(serializer));
```

Here is my customer formatter class:

```
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test.Formatters
{
    public class CustomFormatter: MediaTypeFormatter
    {

        private readonly IJsonSerializer _serializer;

        public CustomFormatter(IJsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            _serializer = serializer;

            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/json"));
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml"));
            SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
            SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.Unicode);
        }

        public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override async Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(readStream);
            string text = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

            var serializedObj = _serializer.Deserialize(type, text);
            return serializedObj;
        }

        public override async Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
        {
            var serializedObj = _serializer.Serialize(value);
            var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet);
            await writeStream.WriteAsync(encoding.GetBytes(serializedObj), 0, encoding.GetBytes(serializedObj).Length);
        }
    }
}
```

In .NetFramework WebAPI **ReadFromStreamAsync** and **WriteToStreamAsync** are triggered perfectly.
However, in WCF they are not triggered even though content-type is "application/json".

How can I handle WCF serialization by myself?

Comment: I dont think WCF is affected by the GlobalConfiguration. You need to enable the WCF web behaviors, try this blog (https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/oct/04/wcf-and-json-services)

Comment: The wcf service only supports three serializers: XMLSerializer, NetDataContractSerializer, and DataContractSerializer. Among them, DataContrcatSerializer is the default serializer of WCF. Your code does not work because WCF does not support it.